# UNIX not being able to access file even after 777 permission

Tags: file, shell, unix, file-permissions

I have file placed at location /orabin/hrtst/TEST :

```
/orabin/hrtst/TEST$ ls -ltr Lookup_code.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 xxhcmuser dba 0 Feb 25 15:08 Lookup_code.log
```

I want the -`rwxrwxrwx` permission to change to `drwxrwxrwx`

What command can I use ?

Comment: **d** is for directory, what you have is a file

Comment: I want to Change permissions on the directory to allow the Oracle user to read and write from it:

Answer (score 1):

`d`, which you're talking about, is not a permission, but, it is a way of representing the nature of the file(which is directory in this case).

`Lookup_code.log` is a regular file. So, you see a `-` in the first place;just before the permissions`(rwx-rwx-rwx)`.

As already mentioned, you need to create a directory with this name; only then you can see the desired `d` there.

Comment: @Am_i_helpful- I am not being able to open my log file from this directory.
the direcorty and the file have all the permisisons. Still not opening in my external table

Comment: @divya.trehan573 - The problem isn't with the file permission; it maybe with the way you're trying to access the file. You can simply access the file using some standard editiors like `vi`,`emacs`,etc. I suggest you to ensure whether the file is accessible from these editors or not. The way you're accessing in your external table is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry mate,

The only way that that is going to change into a d is if you make that file into a directory.

Here is a good reading source: https://kb.iu.edu/d/abdb

That file has permission to be all of the things (except a directory).

Cheers.

### Edit:

Here is a more indepth read:
https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/ls.1.asp